# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When I make a connection from netbeans to DB in SQL 
i select services -> databases -> drivers -> Microsoft Sql server 2005
then connect using.

```
Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=GP using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (Login failed for user 'moataz'.)
```

Comment: Connect using what?

Comment: You need to provide details like from where you are trying to connect, the error that you are facing and stacktrace - the details provided now will not allow anyone to answer your question!

Comment: (Login failed for user 'moataz'.) ---> Is this user registered in the database?
Spelling for username and password is correct?
 Like @N00bPr0grammer already said. Give us more details.

Comment: the problem is solved and it was this user wasn't registered in the database ..thanks alot